# Why user will be asked for access photo permission when first launch app?

Tags: ios, permissions, photo, breakpoints, privacy

When the app is first run it asks for permission to access the photos!

What's the reason for that?

One way is run the code one line by one line or Another way is revert code to previous version.

And find from which version, the app become to ask permission at first launch.

Previously, when we enter select photo screen, we would write code to ask the permission.

I also try to add symbolic breakpoints like:

```
-[UIAlertView initWithTitle:message:delegate:cancelButtonTitle:otherButtonTitles:]
```

And even find a class dump UIAlertView header in order to add symbolic breakpoint but not work. Add UIAlertController breakpoint also does not work.

The simulator OS is 8.3. And each time I must reset contents and setting to reproduce the issue.

Any hint or good idea will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I find out the following code cause the iOS system to pop up the "Allow our App to access their photo gallery" dialog. Thanks for Vijay's answer.

```
[[PHPhotoLibrary sharedPhotoLibrary] registerChangeObserver:self];
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting with iOS 6, Apple now requires apps to get explicit user permission before accessing Contacts, Calendars, Reminders, and Photos. From the "Data Privacy" section in Apple's iOS 6 Release Notes:
In addition to location data, the system now asks the user’s permission before allowing third-party apps to access certain user data, including:

- Contacts
- Calendars
- Reminders
- Photo Library

For contact, calendar, and reminder data, your app needs to be prepared to be denied access to these items and to adjust its behavior accordingly. If the user has not yet been prompted to allow access, the returned structure is valid but contains no records. If the user has denied access, the app receives a NULL value or no data. If the user grants permission to the app, the system subsequently notifies the app that it needs to reload or revert the data.